# Ansible: restricting group vars with groups of groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have an ansible *hosts* file that looks like that:

```
[myhosts]
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2

[group1:children]
myhosts

[group2:children]
myhosts
```

Along side with *group vars* files for **group1** and **group2** (and incidentally for **myhosts**) that are declaring some common variables but with different values.

Here is my directory layout (that follows the [best pratices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout)):

```
hosts
main.yml
group_vars/
    group1.yml
    group2.yml
    myhosts.yml
```

Therefore, both *group vars* files for **group1** and **group2** are automatically included by ansible when an host belongs to both groups.

For the record, I am callinng ansible on my playblook with the following [pattern](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html) as target (specified in command line):

```
192.168.0.1:&group1
```

Considering that, how can I make ansible include only the *group vars* file associated to **group1** (and children group **myhosts**) ? Is that possible ?

An alternate solution would be renaming the *group vars* files of **group1** and **group2** to something different (to prevent automatic includes) and includes those in separate "proxy" playbooks, specific to each subgroup, but this seems less clean to me.

Note: for the moment it is not the case, but in the futur it is likely that group1 and group2 would have few hosts not in common.

Answer (score 3):

The `hosts` value of a play is a way to set the target hosts of the play, **but** it it is not a *view* on those hosts.
If a host belongs to multiple groups it will **always** load vars from the `group_vars` of all those groups, not only the one specified in the play.

Comment: Ok, so I need to do what I wrote in my question ? i.e. having two playbooks each including/defining the specific variables I want for the play

Comment: I don't really have a solution. You have to re-organize your groups so that the hosts doesn't belongs to 2 groups with different values for same vars.